# I tried to install 'Brave' the browser on my raspberry pi 5 and it corrupted the source file I think

Tags: source.list

I've attempted to install Brave on my Raspberry Pi 5 from https://raspberrytips.com/install-brave-browser-raspberry-pi/ and now the source file I think is corrupted. However when I go and view it, it says this:

```
 deb [ arch=armhf ] http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/ bookworm main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/ bookworm main contrib non-free rpi
```

But when I try anything else I get this:

```
apt-get update
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

The previous answer to this question had this:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list
```

and it doesn't work for me.

Can someone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do NOT update `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any old file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Add your *new* sources files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/somenamehere.list`. Undo all your changes (that stuff in `[]` brackets and start in column 1) it should be `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main` then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` to ensure it's working. You can rename files you don't want to use to `somenamehere.list~` and `apt` will ignore it.

Comment: What OS? The Pi5 does not use http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com

Comment: `it doesn't work for me` so, you deleted that file, and the error still says there's a problem with that file? that's unpossible

Comment: Hey Dougie. Thanks for the response. I am very new to this, not sure that I know how to 'undo all your changes'. Apologies for being a dumbarse. I did change the source by the looks of it, although in the 3rd line it shows '#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main

Comment: Dougie, I still get the same error 'E: malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list (type)' and then in the next line 'E: the list of sources could not be read'  This is after I have asked 'sudo apt update' or as you asked above 'sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade'

Comment: Hey Dougie, good news I have bumbled my way through and renamed correctly (I think) and I removed brave-browser-release.list and my update and upgrade prompts work now.

Comment: Jaromanda thanks for getting back to me. Not sure that I know what I'm doing so hard to comment, but I have succesfully removed the .list and now am functioning. I think.

Comment: Milliways thanks for getting back to me. I wasn't sure how to or what to do but have fixed now and learnt a lot.

Comment: If you want help you should edit your question explaining what you are doing - in particular what file you are adding.

Comment: Looks like you have a leading space.  Try removing that.